# How to find correct sources for android device?

Tags: android

I want to look through android sources to understand reason of error. I have android device with `version 4.4.4` which is the same to `API 19`. I downloaded sources for API level 19 (via sdk manager) and wanted to find code which causes error.
In logcat I have error:

```
12-16 16:51:03.790: E/AndroidRuntime(10349): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 16:51:03.790: E/AndroidRuntime(10349):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6596)
12-16 16:51:03.790: E/AndroidRuntime(10349):    at android.widget.TextView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TextView.java:8716)
12-16 16:51:03.790: E/AndroidRuntime(10349):    at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:12538)
```

But problem is that inside TextView class line 6596 is:

```
} else {
```

Line 8716 is comment. So cources are not correspond to an error. How to find correct sources?

Also if check in device `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is 19`.
Device - `Sony Xperia tablet`.

Full logcat
12-16 17:30:43

```
.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6596)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.TextView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TextView.java:8716)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:12538)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(View.java:12289)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16639)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at com.cooperok.gui.views.tablefixheader.TableFixHeaders.makeView(TableFixHeaders.java:741)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at com.cooperok.gui.views.tablefixheader.TableFixHeaders.makeAndSetup(TableFixHeaders.java:698)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at com.cooperok.gui.views.tablefixheader.TableFixHeaders.onLayout(TableFixHeaders.java:601)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14965)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5622)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-16 17:30:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(19327):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is your min sdk?

Comment: minsdk is 15, but sources from version 15 are not corresponds too

Comment: What's the entire logcat ?

Comment: You could be looking to a modified version of TextView. Some phones change the source code of some components

Comment: I think your problem is in your declaration of your TextView (on the XML or .java class). Look at the different declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I looked through origin android source and finded that there is only two posible variants of NullPointerException, so it was easy to guess where problem is

```
/**
 * Check whether entirely new text requires a new view layout
 * or merely a new text layout.
 */
private void checkForRelayout() {
    // If we have a fixed width, we can just swap in a new text layout
    // if the text height stays the same or if the view height is fixed.

    if ((mLayoutParams.width != LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ||
            (mMaxWidthMode == mMinWidthMode && mMaxWidth == mMinWidth)) &&
            (mHint == null || mHintLayout != null) &&
            (mRight - mLeft - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight() > 0)) {
        // Static width, so try making a new text layout.

        int oldht = mLayout.getHeight();
        int want = mLayout.getWidth();
        int hintWant = mHintLayout == null ? 0 : mHintLayout.getWidth();

        /*
         * No need to bring the text into view, since the size is not
         * changing (unless we do the requestLayout(), in which case it
         * will happen at measure).
         */
        makeNewLayout(want, hintWant, UNKNOWN_BORING, UNKNOWN_BORING,
                      mRight - mLeft - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight(),
                      false);

        if (mEllipsize != TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE) {
            // In a fixed-height view, so use our new text layout.
            if (mLayoutParams.height != LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT &&
                mLayoutParams.height != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                invalidate();
                return;
            }

            // Dynamic height, but height has stayed the same,
            // so use our new text layout.
            if (mLayout.getHeight() == oldht &&
                (mHintLayout == null || mHintLayout.getHeight() == oldht)) {
                invalidate();
                return;
            }
        }

        // We lose: the height has changed and we have a dynamic height.
        // Request a new view layout using our new text layout.
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    } else {
        // Dynamic width, so we have no choice but to request a new
        // view layout with a new text layout.
        nullLayouts();
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

In my case TextView was created programatically and mLayoutParams was null so problem was solved by setting LayoutParams to view.
But this is awful that vendors can change android source and don't show these changes (actually I didn't find any information about Sony). I thought that they change only kernel.

Answer (score 1):

To find the right line of the sources, You should have one of Google Nexus devices - pure android devices.

Manufacturers changes the sources of Android for their devices.
It causes wrong line number on logcat.